What was the rationale for expanding the ID space for i.sstatic.net?
The ID space for Imgur's IDs is 5 characters of alphanumeric characters. I noticed that i.sstatic.net has opted instead for 8 characters, while still supporting the 5 characters for images from the Imgur era.
I'm curious what the rationale is for the expansion.
I don't hold anything against the decision. But I am curious. I'd have thought it would have been simpler to keep things consistent. And the Imgur era images only consumed ~2.5% of the 5-character ID space (How much of Stack's imgur image-ID space has been consumed?), so to be honest I'd be surprised if dealing with collisions was a major concern.

Might also be to make it harder to "guess" and reach images at random, though there isn't "private image" feature, so it's just a wild guess. :)

The main public Imgur service uses more characters now.

Even if the chance was small, we still would have had to deal with collisions when our unique ID generator was put into place. It was easy enough to pick a new length to avoid any potential collisions. Six characters also had the potential of collisions because some five-character images also included a sixth character used to denote thumbnails/resizing.
It also gives us the added benefit, if ever needed, of knowing if an image originally came from Imgur or our new service.

I still find it hard to imagine those problems (collisions and differentiating eras) being more difficult to solve without expanding the ID space.

@starball well, even with minimal gain, it's zero effort, zero downsides - so can't see why not. :-)

@Troy maybe worth to mention your ID generator use only lower case letters, while imgur's also use upper case? Or did I get it wrong when doing some trial and error today to check the algorithm?

I can see no upsides to documenting (even as lightly as "the id is comprised of lower case letters") the current generator algo... It'd make the id format pseudo-contractual when there's nothing to gain by doing so

There is nothing secret about it. The ids are alphanumeric, upper and lower case. My own profile image has uppercase letters in it: https://i.sstatic.net/vTsnIREos.jpg
